# How to create correct JSONArray in java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am trying to create a JSONArray but There is only one json object in array is coming DEMO2 why DEMO1 is not getting fetched?

```
 Map<String, Object> payload = objectMapper.convertValue(request.getPayload(), Map.class);
     
 JSONObject seg = new JSONObject();
 seg.put("s_code", "DEMO1");
 seg.put("v_type", "backend");
      
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
 seg.put("s_code", "DEMO2");
 seg.put("v_type", "frontend");
      
 JSONArray segment = new JSONArray();
 segment.add(seg);
 segment.add(obj);
      
 payload.put("segments",segment);
```

There is only one json object in array DEMO2 why DEMO1 is not getting fetched?
Edit:- Storing in jsonArray because need it that way I am extraction value like this

```
JSONArray segmentsList = payloadObject.getJSONArray("segments");
```

And output coming like this because of empty {} brackets my code is failing

```
 segments=[{v_type=frontend, s_code=LOC_DEMO_SEGMENT}, {}]
```

Comment: Because I need it in jsonarray form where I am extracting the value

Comment: @Harsh Like this JSONArray segmentsList = payloadObject.getJSONArray("segments");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are overriding value of `seg`. So at second place you need to put DEMO2 in `obj`, not `seg`. Check the updated code below.

```
Map<String, Object> payload = objectMapper.convertValue(request.getPayload(), Map.class);
     
JSONObject seg = new JSONObject();
seg.put("s_code", "DEMO1");
seg.put("v_type", "backend");
      
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("s_code", "DEMO2"); // Here is the change
obj.put("v_type", "frontend"); // Here is the change
      
JSONArray segment = new JSONArray();
segment.add(seg);
segment.add(obj);
      
payload.put("segments",segment);
```